# Adding ID to Text Output in AWS Batch Transform Job with DistilBERT Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface, huggingface-hub

I have a dataset in JSON format with ‘id’ and ‘text’ columns. Currently, I’m using the following pipeline configuration in AWS:

```
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'distilbert-base-uncased',
    'HF_TASK':'feature-extraction'
}
# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
   env=hub,                                                # configuration for loading model from Hub
   role=role,                                              # IAM role with permissions to create an endpoint
   transformers_version="4.26",                             # Transformers version used
   pytorch_version="1.13",                                  # PyTorch version used
   py_version='py39',                                      # Python version used
)
# create Transformer to run our batch job
batch_job = huggingface_model.transformer(
    
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
    output_path=output_s3_path, # we are using the same s3 path to save the output with the input
    strategy='SingleRecord')
```

I’m using a batch transform job to generate the output, which currently contains only the extracted text. However, I also want to include the ‘id’ associated with each text in the output file. Is there a way to achieve this, and if so, how can I modify my configuration to include the ‘id’ in the output file? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can associate the input with the output in a Batch Transform Job. See:

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform-data-processing.html#batch-transform-data-processing-workflow:~:text=%3A%20%22%24%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,Example%3A%20Output%20Inferences%20Joined%20with%20Input%20Data,-If%20you%27re%20using](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform-data-processing.html#batch-transform-data-processing-workflow:%7E:text=%3A%20%22%24%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,Example%3A%20Output%20Inferences%20Joined%20with%20Input%20Data,-If%20you%27re%20using)

In your `.transform()` method you use the `input_filter` and `output_filter` to asociate your input and output `key:value` pairs respectively.

```
sm_transformer.transform(…, input_filter="$", join_source= "Input", output_filter="$")
```